How to derive absolute temperature scale from Carnot engine?
This question is about how to obtain an absolute or thermodynamic temperature scale using a Carnot engine.
The reasoning below appears in the book "Heat and Thermodynamics" by Zemansky and Dittman.
The thermal efficiency of a Carnot engine $R$ operating a hot reservoir with temperature $T_H$ and a cold reservoir with temperature $T_C$ is
$$\mathcal{\eta}_R=1+\frac{Q_L}{Q_H}=1-\frac{|Q_L|}{|Q_H|}=\phi(T_H,T_L)\tag{1}$$
where $Q_H$ and $Q_L$ are the heats absorbed and transferred to the hot and cold reservoirs, respectively, in a Carnot cycle and $\phi$ is an unknown function.
Note that if the engine is reversible, then as far as I can tell, $\phi$ is known
$$\phi(T_H,T_L)=1-\frac{T_C}{T_H}\tag{2}$$
Saying that $\phi$ is unknown appears to mean that we are considering Carnot engines in general, including irreversible Carnot engines.
On the other hand, I thought that a Carnot engine was by definition a reversible engine. Thus, I am a bit confused here.
Rearranging (1) we obtain
$$\frac{|Q_H|}{|Q_L|}=\frac{1}{1-\phi(T_H,T_L)}=f(T_H,T_L)\tag{3}$$
where $f(T_H,T_L)$ is another unknown function in general.
Consider now three Carnot engines $R_A,R_B,$, and $R_C$ operating between three reservoirs as shown below

where $T_1>T_3>T_2$.
We can apply (3) to each of the engines
$$\frac{|Q_1|}{|Q_2|}=f(T_1,T_2)\tag{A}$$
$$\frac{|Q_1|}{|Q_3|}=f(T_1,T_3)\tag{B}$$
$$\frac{|Q_3|}{|Q_2|}=f(T_3,T_2)\tag{C}$$
The book does not mention this but the fact that $f$ is the same in all three expressions is, I think, due to the fact that the Carnot engines are the exact same engines (that is, given the same two reservoirs, they are implementing the same exact thermodynamic cycle).
Then
$$f(T_1,T_2)=\frac{|Q_1|}{|Q_2|}=\frac{|Q_1|/|Q_3|}{|Q_2|/|Q_3|}=\frac{f(T_1,T_3)}{f(T_2,T_3)}\tag{4}$$
$T_3$ is arbitrarily chosen in the interval $(T_2,T_1)$.

Since it does not appear on the two left-hand expressions in (4) it
must not appear in the two right-hand expressions.

Thus
$$\frac{|Q_1|}{|Q_2|}=\frac{\psi(T_1)}{\psi(T_2)}$$

The ratio on the right is defined as the ratio of two thermodynamic
temperatures and is denoted $T_1/T_2$.

$$\frac{|Q_1|}{|Q_2|}=\frac{T_1}{T_2}$$

Thus, two temperatures on the thermodynamic scale are to each other as
the absolute values of the heats absorbed and rejected, respectively,
by a Carnot engine operating between reservoirs at these temperatures.

My questions are about some of these last steps.
What justifies going from $\frac{\psi(T_1)}{\psi(T_2)}$ to $\frac{T_1}{T_2}$?
Here are my thoughts.
We are trying to assign numbers to temperatures.
Temperature itself seems to arise from the zeroth law of thermodynamics: it is a property that determines whether or not a system is in thermal equilibrium with other systems.
Assigning a number to a temperature of a system is basically assigning a number to the isotherms of the system based on some standard system with specific thermodynamic coordinates. This standard system is called a thermometer.
The assignment happens through a (thermometric) function $\theta(X)$ where $X$ is some specific (thermometric) property of the system that we are varying.
This all gives us an empirical temperature scale and there are many different ones depending on what we choose as the thermometer, the thermometric property and the thermometric function.
The absolute temperature scale we are trying to come up with is independent of these variables.
Since the operation of a specific Carnot cycle among the general possible (reversible or not) Carnot cycles is independent of the working substance and depends only on temperature of the reservoirs, we are trying to establish a temperature scale that is determined by this cycle.
By operation of reversible Carnot engine I means the heats exchanged, the work done, and the thermal efficiency.
What is done in the calculations above is to define relative temperatures based on energy in a Carnot cycle.
But here lies the doubt I cannot solve: the energies depend on the given specific cycle. The cycle may be irreversible.
Thus, the exact relationship between $T_1$ and $T_2$ in terms of the energies seems to depend on the specific Carnot cycle used.
In other words, the exact functional form of $\psi(T)$ seems to depend on the type of Carnot cycle that is used.
Why is it that we can just choose an arbitrary $\psi(T)$ to define the relationship for any Carnot cycle?
If we choose to define the relationship between the temperatures based on the reversible Carnot cycle with reservoirs at these temperatures, then it seems to me that the unknown functional forms are actually known.

I believe that in the Zemansky-Dittman book (7th edition), section 7.5, pages 176-178, in the text and equations where $T_1,T_2,T_3,etc.,...,$ is written the variables should be changed to $\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3,etc.,...$ resp., with the added comment that $\tau$ now denotes the empirical temperature as measured by an arbitrary thermometer and we assume that the Carnot engine is operating in the temperature range where the thermometer reading is monotonic.
With this assumption you have the equation
$$\frac{|Q_1|}{|Q_2|}=\frac{\psi(\tau_1)}{\psi(\tau_2)}$$
and now you can define the absolute temperature scale as $$T=\psi(\tau)$$ and then you get
$$\frac{|Q_1|}{|Q_2|}=\frac{T_1}{T_2}$$
